# How to uglify or minify C code

Tags: c, gcc, minify

Using `gcc` I can remove comments and unwanted blank lines, but I want to reduce a size of file also, is there any options in `gcc` or any other tool to do so

At present I do like this

```
gcc -fpreprocessed -dD -E  -P source_code.c > source_code_comments_removed.c
```

Here is scenario assume that this is my source_code.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{ 
      // declar variable i
      int i=0;

      /* multiline comment
      for loop
      demo stuff
      */
      for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
      {
            // just print something
            printf("Hello %d \n",i);
      }

}
```

I want to minify like this, removed comments and blank lines

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){int i=0;for(i=1; i<=5; i++){printf("Hello %d \n",i);}}
```

**Note :** I am on **Linux** please don't suggest any windows based solution

Comment: Why do you need minification? Please note, that this won't change the size of output executable file - there's no need to minify C code, as you do with javascript on web applications for example

Comment: for "uglification" here is a tool: http://www.brothersoft.com/mangle-it-c%2B%2B-obfuscator-91793.html

Comment: I know that executable file size will not change, but when you have many source code to compile, if I reduce size of each source code, then total package size can be reduced right ?

Comment: If you zip up your source then I doubt minification will make much difference

Comment: Or you could be going to [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/)!

Comment: If you are trying to speed up compile time of your builds with gcc, I would recommend you look at [`distcc`](https://github.com/distcc/distcc) and [`ccache`](https://ccache.samba.org/) instead of uglifying your code.

Comment: @samgak Zipping is compression not minification

Comment: Are you running out if disk space? You won't ever edit that code again? Anything else has no sense, IMO. (and is easier to buy new disk). Seriously: why? Ultimate reason, "reduce package size" isn't root motivation, moreover what do you mean with "package"?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti No my dear, I don't have any such issue, I am just curious to know whether its possible for C code as well, since in past I did it for javascript, php so

Comment: @user3637224 Total package size of what? If you distribute the binaries, the size of the source doesn't matter. If you distribute the source, then what for, if the user can't inspect it or make modifications?

Comment: Of course it's possible, but there is no point so nobody is doing it.

Comment: Yes, zipping is not minification, but if your goal is to reduce the source package size then minification + zipping will not be much better than just zipping since the compressor will effectively encode whitespace.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Use a good build system (even make) so that you never compile .c->.o unless the .c changes.Compressing the C source is then worse than useless. NB most of the cost of compiling the average C source file is in parsing and expanding macros of C header files. Compressing the source is solving a non-problem. Parallel compilation if you have mp resources is another way forward.

Comment: @milleniumbug : package will not cross even 50MB, since you said its possible can you please show me, how this could be done, I am just curious to learn new things please my dear.

Comment: Just for curiosity? Ah, ok Then! Yes, it's possible and it won't change almost anything for compiler (maybe speed but so little you cannot even measure). I don't know about tools: it's pretty unusual to try to make C code ugly and/or minify it.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti : Yes I am curious

Comment: The reason you do this in javascript is because javascript sources get downloaded from server to client browser. So you try to reduce network usage. C sources do not get downloaded or transferred anywhere - so it's beyond stupid to do this. Also C source code doesn't go into your 'package' - once C code is compiled it's not bundled into any binary. Debugging also becomes difficult if you minify your code, because you cannot easily put a breakpoint on one executable line of code, in most debuggers

Comment: In case someone else will have inspiration from this post: I'm not aware of anything to do it but I'm sure it's possible to **verbosify** JavaScript code... Lol

Comment: Thank You all, instead of comment someone write answer, I will accept the good one, so that in future if any idiot like me, tries to do so, then he can read it, and let him realize there is no point in minification in case of C

Comment: Just save the `.o` files. When you don't want anybody to change or understand your source code than it's perfect. It's very ugly to make C source code from object files, but there are some girls out there than can disassemble and read that output to write C code again.

Comment: How is this stupid? Looks like a lot of fun to me. Why not write a program which does this and adds random text in comments in random places and random new lines wherever random new lines can be added. Sounds like this could be used to make a fun prank or something. You could hold you boss to ransom by "randomifying" his code and exchanging him the "antidote program" which you have also written (which reverses the changes) in exchange for a extra-large bonus this year.

Comment: Alternatively you get yourself fired.

Comment: JIT compilation allows C to be compiled specifically for the platform and device that will be executing the code.  In this case the code comes from a file or string and could indeed benefit from minification.   You may not have encountered it yet, but it exists and has been around for a few years, I'm using it right now, and you may be seeing more of it in the future. :)  People are also finding other reasons to use JIT compilation, such as Hot-Module-Reloading.

Comment: There's cuglify too: http://www.systomath.com/doc/LibStmCL32Devl/html/cuglify_8c-source.html

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>`
`main(){for(int i=1;i<6;i++)printf("Hello %d \n",i);}` is even shorter

Comment: [bisecting](https://github.com/googleprojectzero/halfempty) is one use case for minification

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```sh
sed -rb 's/ {6}//g' main.c |
sed -rb 's/\/\/.*$//g' |
tr -d '\n' |
sed -rb 's/\/\*.*\*\///g' |
sed -rb 's/(#include.*>)/\1\n/g'
```

will give you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){int i=0;for(i=1; i<=5; i++){printf("Hello %d \n",i);}}
```

**However**, as stated in the in the comments, this doesn't make much sense and will **not reduce the size** of your compiled object file!

Comment: But this is I guess very specific to this type of code. You need to add many other things like, #define or other directives

Comment: @shreyans800755 Right, but the main point here is that it will not reduce the size of the object file.

Comment: That's true, but still sometimes it is required, mostly on competition when you are supposed to write obfuscated code like IOCCC

Comment: What is about #define?

Comment: Not all distributed c code is compiled.  OpenCL programs, for example, read C code from a file or string and rely on a JIT compiler for portability.

Comment: Full minification would be much more complex - remove comments, remove non-newline whitespace (but not inside strings), remove newlines (but not if 1st char on line was '#' and not forgetting to handle backslash/continuation properly); then reduce symbol names (e.g. `foo` replaced with `f`); then start doing the hard stuff (like replacing `int i = 0; for(i=1...` with `for(int i=1...`). Would take a lot of work.

Comment: perhaps reduce project size, I guess.

Comment: I think it's much fun to minify code by yourself! Minified code has no real practical value to me and I would never suggest using it on any real project but the progress of minification by hand (let's say on a competetive coding site) really makes you think in funny ways that might add to your non-minification programming skills :-)

Comment: it's useful for times when you cannot move a file over SFTP, so you have to connect over putty and copy and paste the file contents (sometimes MB big) on slow VPN connections